# How to convert query into array json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, oracle, jsp

I have query which gives an output like this :

```
{ key:1,label:"R. Bulan"}
{ key:2,label:"R. Bintang"}
{ key:3,label:"R. Akasia"}
{ key:4,label:"R. Guest Room"}
```

This is my query :

```
select '{ '||'key:'||IDMEETINGROOM||''||',label:"'||NAMARUANG||'"'||'} ' json
    from MMEETING_ROOM  where IDLOKASI='I' order by IDMEETINGROOM;
```

In javascript I insert into an array variable like this:

```
var event = new array();
 event.push(<query>);
```

and the output become :

```
event = ["{ key:1,label:"R. Bulan"}","{ key:2,label:"R. Bintang"}","{ key:3,label:"R. Akasia"}","{ key:4,label:"R. Guest Room"}"]
```

How can I make the output not as a String Array but should look like this :

```
event =[
    { key:1,label:"R. Bulan"},
    { key:2,label:"R. Bintang"},
    { key:3,label:"R. Akasia"},
    { key:4,label:"R. Guest Room"}
];
```

Comment: Whats your backend script? php?

Comment: Try `event.push(JSON.parse(<query>));`

Comment: @Eddie : I used JSP,

at charlietfl : okay I'll try first

Comment: still cannot, my output : Array [ "{key:1,label:R. Bulan}", "{key:2,label:R. Bintang}", "{key:3,label:R. Akasia}", "{key:4,label:R. Guest Room}" ] when I used parse the give me an error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse it back from string to Object, use `JSON.parse()`
 to convert it.

**Update 11:50**

Ok, the problem is: your returns data is not JSON valid, its missing double quote so the JSON.parse cannot parse it for you

So I do some trick with the string replace here:

```
    data = data.getElementsByTagName('SEARCH')[0].childNodes;
    var sections=new Array();
    if (data.length > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var item = JSON.parse(Url.decode(data[i].chil‌​dNodes[0].firstChild‌​.data).replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, "\"$1\":\"$2\""))
            sections.push(item);
        }
    }
    console.log(sections);
```

Comment: still cannot,
my output :
Array [ "{key:1,label:R. Bulan}", "{key:2,label:R. Bintang}", "{key:3,label:R. Akasia}", "{key:4,label:R. Guest Room}" ]

when I used parse the give me an error :
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Can you provide the <query> look like? Or the `push` section if possible

Comment: "{key:1,label:R. Bulan}", "{key:2,label:R. Bintang}", "{key:3,label:R. Akasia}", "{key:4,label:R. Guest Room}"  here looks like.

I want to remove mark < " > before { and after  } < " > so the array structure can become like I want

Comment: my code :data=data.getElementsByTagName('SEARCH')[0].childNodes;var sections=new Array();if (data.length > 0){for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){sections.push(Url.decode(data[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.data)); }}console.log(sections);

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- Your `output` is not having a valid `JSON`.

  [image]
- Use [JSON.Parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to parses a `JSON string` and then push the resulted `JSON Object` into the `event` array.

  ```
  var event = new array();
  event.push(JSON.parse(<query>));
  ```

Then resulted output will be like this **:**

```
console.log(event);
```

**Output :**

```
[{
        "key": 1,
        "label": "R.Bulan"
    }, {
        "key": 2,
        "label": "R.Bintang"
    },
    {
        "key": 3,
        "label": "R.Akasia"
    },
    {
        "key": 4,
        "label": "R.Guest Room"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has build in support for JSON (since 12.1.0.2).
You can use JSON_OBJECT and JSON_ARRAYAGG to create the JSON you want.
See below:

```
create table MMEETING_ROOM (IDMEETINGROOM NUMBER,  
                            NAMARUANG VARCHAR2(40));
insert into MMEETING_ROOM values(1,'R. Bulan');
insert into MMEETING_ROOM values(2,'R. Bintang');
insert into MMEETING_ROOM values(3,'R. Akasia');
insert into MMEETING_ROOM values(4,'R. Guest Room');


commit;

SELECT JSON_OBJECT('key' VALUE IDMEETINGROOM,
                   'label' VALUE NAMARUANG)
FROM MMEETING_ROOM;


JSON_OBJECT('KEY'VALUEIDMEETINGROOM,'LABEL'VALUENAMARUANG)
---------------------------------------------------------------
{"key":1,"label":"R. Bulan"}
{"key":2,"label":"R. Bintang"}
{"key":3,"label":"R. Akasia"}
{"key":4,"label":"R. Guest Room"}
```

and to create the array

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT('key' VALUE IDMEETINGROOM,
                                  'label' VALUE NAMARUANG))
FROM MMEETING_ROOM;

JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('KEY'VALUEIDMEETINGROOM,'LABEL'VALUENAMARUANG))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"key":1,"label":"R. Bulan"},
 {"key":2,"label":"R. Bintang"},
 {"key":3,"label":"R. Akasia"},
 {"key":4,"label":"R. Guest Room"}]
```